Are there dedicated symbols for interval qualities?
I want to describe harmonic intervals between two notes in text. Given that key and mode are not specified in this context, are there dedicated symbols to signify a major, minor, perfect, diminished or an augmented quality of a harmonic interval? I'm looking for alternatives to write it out in plain text.

If you're looking for non-alphanumeric symbols, then no.
The most commonly used abbreviations:

d = diminished
m = minor
P = perfect
M = major
A = augmented

And the complete interval would be written { quality }{ magnitude }

d5 = diminished fifth
m2 = minor second
P4 = perfect fourth
M3 = major third
A6 = augmented sixth

Interval qualities are key/mode independent. They depend only on the spelling of the notes involved.

C-D# = augmented second
C-Eb = minor third


Great, thanks! I realize I expected chord quality-like symbols, like + or o. But using abbreviations seems like the obvious choice!

Adding to Aaron's answer, still using buttons readily available on a qwerty board.
- for minor.
+ for augmented.
o for diminished.
0 for half diminished.
M or maj for major.
m or mi or min for minor.
So, for example, C>E♭ could be typed as -3, m3, mi3 or min3.

Chord symbols are different to interval symbols.  What is a sharp interval? etc.  Also, the symbol for half diminished should be an “o“ with a slash: “ø”.  But again, that’s a chord symbol, not an interval.

@ElementsInSpace - strange  - when I typed in zero, it showed as O with a slash. Then presented without one.

The number zero has a slash in the editor view, but that’s because it’s using a different font.

@ElementsInSpace - that's become obvious - now!!

@ElementsInSpace & Tim: the zero has a slash in neither view on my phone.
